# FInd duplicates on output

Tags: javascript

I submit some data via AJAX post and when I get receive response I output it via a loop.

```
$.each(data, function() {
    $("#em").append('<i class="bi bi-pin-map-fill'+(lat == this.lat && lon == this.lon ? " bg-danger" : "")+'"></i> '+this.lat+' '+this.lon);

    let lat = this.lat,
        lon = this.lon;
}
```

In some case the coordinates I receive could be of the exact same location, so I'd like to be able to mark those duplicates by adding background color. So I've added a condition to check for matches but am blanking how to implement it, since I can't really set the vars at the end of my loop... Need some nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you could declare a coordinate array before your loop, then in the loop test if the current coordinate is already in the array with `includes` method.

For example:

```
const coordArray = [];
$.each(data, function() {
   const isCoordDupli = coordArray.includes(`${this.lat} ${this.long}`);
   $("#em").append('<i class="bi bi-pin-map-fill'+(isCoordDupli ? " bg-danger" : "")+'"></i> '+this.lat+' '+this.lon);

   coordArray.push(`${this.lat} ${this.long}`);
});
```